# How do I add a column to an already existing text file in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, addition, txt

How do I add a column to an already existing text file in Python? First I just want to add the header, then through my investigation add values in the column.

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific: what is the format of the input file, are there any other columns in it? Also, if I understood correctly, you want to perform your investigation, and add values to the column while doing so? It is all possible, but more details are need.

Comment: Thank you for responding atru. It is a file with txt extension, containing a matrix of 24 columns and 270 rows, plus a row with headings on the top, and I want to add a column as a 25th column with zeros and with the heading CLASS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal solution that does what you asked for, and gives you an overview of some useful Python features. Importantly, what you want to do can probably be done very easily with pandas but I don't use it, so the solution is plain Python. It can also be done quite differently if you want to use numpy, more efficiently too.

This is it,

```
input_file = 'test.txt'
output_file = 'mod_test.txt'

header = ''
matrix = []

# Parse and store all existing lines
with open(input_file, 'r') as fin:

    # The header - remove the newline character only
    header = next(fin).strip()

    # The data - parse and store each line as a list
    # of strings, store as a sublist of matrix
    for line in fin:
        matrix.append(line.strip().split())

# Update the header - now a newline is needed
header += ' CLASS\n'

# Now perform your calculations for each row
# and add new column - adding 0.0 as in the comment
for row in matrix:

    # Calculations would go here

    # This zero is already a string, normally a
    # conversion would be needed
    row.append('0.0')


# Write it to the new file
with open(output_file, 'w') as fout:

    # First the updated header
    fout.write(header)

    for row in matrix:
        # Turn the entries into a single string
        fout.write((' ').join(row) + '\n')
```

And this is a simple demonstration file that can go with it, `test.txt`,

```
C1 C2 C3
1.0 2.0 2.1
2.0 3.0 3.2
3.0 4.0 3.5
```

The comments highlight the most important details, but you should research each technique on your own, they are very useful when working with files.

Basically, you first load the original matrix, then modify it - add the last column, then save it into a different file. To save it to the same file you can just adjust `output_file` or use `input_file` in both cases. Writing to a different file, especially during development and debugging sounds like a better idea.

The new calculations and the writing can all be done in the same place, and if it is only adding a column of 0.0s that is probably a better way - right now the code is unnecessarily stretched. However, if you want to actually perform some more involving calculations, I recommend keeping this structure (also putting any longer calculations in separate functions).